# Passing multiple code blocks as arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, yield

I have a method which takes a code block.

```
def opportunity
  @opportunities += 1
  if yield
    @performances +=1
  end
end
```

and I call it like this:

`opportunity { @some_array.empty? }`

But how do I pass it more than one code block so that I could use yield twice, something like this:

```
def opportunity
  if yield_1
    @opportunities += 1
  end
  if yield_2
    @performances +=1
  end
end
```

and:

```
opportunity {@some_other_array.empty?} { @some_array.empty? }
```

I am aware that this example could be done without yield, but it's just to illustrate.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can't pass multiple blocks, per se, but you can pass multiple procs or lambdas:

Using 1.9 syntax:

```
opportunity ->{ @some_array.empty? }, ->{ @some_other_array.empty? }
```

and in the method itself:

```
def opportunity(lambda1, lambda2)
  if lambda1.()
    @opportunities += 1
  end
  if lambda2.()
    @performances += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it other way to declare that functions

Comment: Proc.new {} or lambda {} also work. Any object that responds to `call` will work

Comment: Is the method `.()` an alias of `.call` ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji YES! http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#method-i-call " Note that prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide “call”."