# Is it possible to pass more than one block to a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, block, codeblocks

Something like:

```
def foo(&b1, &b2)
  b1.call
  b2.call
end

foo() { puts "one" } { puts "two" }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing multiple codeblocks as arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463612/passing-multiple-codeblocks-as-arguments)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't pass multiple blocks in *that* way, but you *can* pass multiple [`proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html) or `lambda` objects:

```
irb(main):005:0> def foo(b1, b2)
irb(main):006:1>   b1.call
irb(main):007:1>   b2.call
irb(main):008:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> foo(Proc.new {puts 'one'}, Proc.new {puts 'two'})
one
two
=> nil
irb(main):010:0>
```

Comment: Ok I see. I could also use lambda { puts "bla" } I suppose. I guess the bottom line is that I can only use &block at most once in a method definition. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

syntax is a lot cuter in Ruby 1.9:

```
foo ->{puts :one}, ->{puts :two}
```

Comment: Note that this replaces `foo(Proc.new {puts 'one'}, Proc.new {puts 'two'})` in [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558899), you still need to define the function as `foo(b1,b2)`, not `foo(&b1, &b2)`